# How to query and compare values of two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need some input on my query. What I am attempting to do is compare a time entered by the user to a block of times stored in a database to check to see if that time slot is available.

The problem I am running into however is the user's value is in one table and the block of values in another table. My query is below. Any help would be appreciated. I have exhausted all my ideas!

```
EmpID = FOREIGN KEY
```

EXAMPLE:

User Enters - 2016-04-06 09-00-00 (of type date time in DB)
I then run what I thought was this query below and see if there is a time
block available between lets say 2016-04-06 09-00-00 AND 2016-04-06 10-00-00

I then update that time as being OK to be scheduled.

```
UPDATE TimeRequestedTable
SET AppointTime = "inputed by user"
WHERE EmpID IN 
      (SELECT BlockTimesTable.EmpID
       FROM BlockTimesTable
       WHERE
         (SELECT AppointTime
          FROM TimeRequestedTable)
       BETWEEN startTime and EndTime);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data for the two tables and for the desired result

Comment: I Provided and example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need an inner join update

```
UPDATE TimeRequestedTable
INNER JOIN BlockTimesTable ON BlockTimesTable.EmpID = TimeRequestedTable.EmpID
SET AppointTime = "inputed by user"
WHERE AppointTime BETWEEN startTime and EndTime
```

Comment: Will this work even though AppointmentTime is not in BlockTimesTable? I thought of this but disproved it when I thought of that. --Thanks